Do the early Coptic translations of John 1:1c prove that "and The Word was a god" is objectively a legitimate translation?
I've long suspected that "and the word was a god' is a legitimate literal translation of John 1:1c into English.
The problem is that there is no indefinite article in Greek so there is often uncertainty about when or where it should be supplied in English translations and typically the idea of supplying an indefinite article here is heavily criticized due to arguments involving contextual theological considerations.
So isn't it interesting that in the earliest available translation of the Greek into a language, Sahidic Coptic, that uses an indefinite article, the indefinite article is found supplied for the word for god in John 1:1c
Does this not show that if it is legitimate to use the indefinite article for the translation of the Greek theos into Coptic for those familiar with Greek and scripture in the 2nd and/or 3rd century it should be legitimate to do so today for translations into English?

Clarification 1:
In distinction from In John 1:1c, should the Greek word θεὸς be translated into English as “a god” or “God”?
The question is bout whether or not the translation "and the word (or The Word) was a god" is objectively legitimate as a literal translation given the Coptic translations as opposed to "should" it be translated one way or the other.
There can be multiple legitimate ways to translate a given text depending on translation philosophy and certainly, some translations are more useful than others. The question is about legitimacy as a more literal translation of the Greek into English and not about whether the translation is the most useful.
It's also different from John 1:1c Out of context, how would a native reader of Koine Greek understand the text?, given that the Coptic translators are seemingly translating in context.
Clarification 2:
The aim of this translation offering is not meant to prove or disprove any particular theology, such as the Trinity. As a matter of fact what is very interesting is that, of the two earliest family of texts, we have one, the Sahidic Coptic, from the second or third century before the Nicene Council, and the other, Coptic Bohairic, which also uses the indefinite article with the word god from around the sixth century well after the Nicene Council. If the Coptic readers were always Trinitarians or eventually became Trinitarians it seems they didn't have a problem with the implications of consistently across the centuries translating John 1:1c with the indefinite article for their theology.
Clarification 3:
The indefinite article even in English doesn't necessarily mean that the noun is indefinite. Sometimes the indefinite article describes the quality or category of the noun. For example, "My pet fluffy is a dog," is being used not to describe Fluffy as some indefinite being, but to specify what kind of being that my specific Fluffy is.
Clarification 4:
This answer is not meant to be in support of the NWT. I've never read the NWT except the few excerpts cited on this website. It may support the NWT but that's not my intent.

Before answering such a question, one would need to determine whether there is evidence (or not) that the translators were biased in any direction and wanted to the Scriptures to say something that it did not say.

@Dottard, there are biases in every translation. Some more than others. The question is passage by passage, whether a given translation is reasonable a literal translation. I think the fact that Egyptian Christians were so important to the Trinity saga in advocacy of it, it seems unlikely that an overtly anti-trinitarian bias would persist in this very verse for several centuries, from the third century until the 6th across multiple dialects.

@Austin, There was an active heresy during the very period you're discussing. It was one of the primary causes of the first council at Nicaea. The Arian heresy argued that Jesus was a separate being from God the Father. The heresy flourished in many areas. A biased translation is not without precedent given some of the opinions floating around at the time.

@AFrazier, where was this "heresy" primarily located? Did it last into the 6th century,  2 centuries after Nicea?

@AFrazier, was Egypt a hot bed for this "heresy"?

There are accounts of it well into the sixth century, during the time of Dionysius Exigus and others. There are even well-circulated church documents that were disavowed because the proponents of it were of that persuasion. The heresy was widespread enough that it provoked attention at the first council. There aren't exactly colored maps available to document the specific towns and municipalities where it flourished specifically. What's relevant is that it existed into the sixth century, and it was a widespread heresy.

I couldn't say if Egypt specifically was a hotbed for that heresy. But I can say that Alexandria was a major Christian epicenter of learning. It's one place where one with an alternative view would certainly seek and/or find acceptance. Gnostic concepts, for example, are known to have circulated in Egypt.

@Austin - the Arian heresy is named after Arius who came from Africa, Libya.  His teachings precipitated the Council in 325.

@AFrazier, yeah. I don't know. The gnostic heresy was in major decline by the end of the 4th century and Arian theology was not well known in Egypt given the influence of Athanasius. It just doesn't seem likely at all that overt anti-trinitarian bias could persist in Egypt of all places across multiple dialects from the second century and into the 6th.

An issue with the logic underlying the question is the assumption the indefinite article would be understood as "a" god not "a" God. If the writer understood ho theos as God the Father, God the Son, God the Spirit. Speaking of only one doesn't automatically mean the writer did not think in terms of God. After all, without the ability to capitalize the Father would be a God. In which case the correct statement is the Word was not ho theos and never the Word was a theos.

@Austin - Was only just able to check out the actual question here - busy family day. This is a great question and having already been familiar with the Coptic translation, I am right there with you. + 1.

The Coptic translation mentioned in the question does not prove anything. The idea of calling the visible manifestation of the invisible God "the word of God", was created by the ancient rabbis. It was based on the Hebrew text of the OT, and was the most prevalent in the rabbinic commentaries in Aramaic, we know as the Targums. Those text were translated into Greek for the Greek-speaking Jews. Hence, the theology of the Logos in the writings of Philo of Alexandria.
If the Coptic translators understood the context and the history of the second temple Judaism, they would newer translate that Logos is a god.
Similar question has already been asked. So instead of wasting time and repeating myself, I am going to copy and paste my answer from four months ago.
Is Jesus "THE word of God" or "A WORD of God"?
According to ancient biblical theology developed after the return from the Babylonian exile, the Word of God (called Memra in Aramaic) is a manifestation of God himself. The concept was based on the various texts of the Old Testament. The scriptures teach that no man can see God, and yet some did see Him. That paradox led to the creation of Memra theology of God having two forms. The unperceivable and unseen form we call today God the Father. And, the perceivable by our senses, called the Word of God (Memra/Logos). It would be every manifestation of God, which a human can see, hear or feel. What started as an observation during the careful reading of the text of the bible fully materialized in the person of Jesus Christ. What followed was over a century of debates between the believing Jews seeing Jesus as a full manifestation of the Word of God (Memra/Logos) and unbelieving ones rejecting it. Eventually the whole concept was branded as heretical by the mainstream rabbinical Judaism in the second century A.D. Since it was too Christian like they got read of it completely. The memory of it was largely forgotten until recently. The Islamic theology developed over a half millennium later, and influenced by the Neoplatonism, had no frame of reference or understanding of those ideas.
The authors of the New Testament knew and fully embraced the philosophy of the Memra. Since the language of the NT is Greek, we know it as Logos. The opening of John's gospel (John 1:1-4) is the best proof of that:

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
was God. He was with God in the beginning. Through him all things were
made; without him nothing was made that has been made. In him was
life, and that life was the light of all mankind.

The New Testament scriptures talking about God the Father:

Now to the King eternal, immortal, invisible, the only God, be honor
and glory for ever and ever. Amen. (1 Timothy 1:17)
He alone can never die, and he lives in light so brilliant that no
human can approach him. No human eye has ever seen him, nor ever will.
All honor and power to him forever! Amen. (1 Timothy 6:16)
No one has ever seen God; but if we love one another, God lives in us
and his love is made complete in us. (1 John 4:12)

The scriptures calling Jesus Christ the image of invisible God:

The Son is the radiance of God’s glory and the exact representation of
His nature, upholding all things by His powerful word. After He had
provided purification for sins, He sat down at the right hand of the
Majesty on high. (Hebrews 1:3)
No one has ever seen God, but the one and only Son, who is himself God
and is in closest relationship with the Father, has made him known.
(John 1:18 )

A handful of quotes from the targums (rabbinic interpretations of the OT in Aramaic) talking about the Word of God (Memra/Logos):

And the Word of the Lord created man in His likeness, in the likeness
of the presence of the Lord He created him, the male and his
yoke-fellow He created them. (Targum Jerusalem, Genesis 1:27)
Walking in the garden in the strength of the day...And the Word of the
Lord God called to Adam, and said to him, Behold, the world which I
have created is manifest before Me; and how thinkest thou that the
place in the midst whereof thou art, is not revealed before Me? Where
is the commandment that I taught thee? (Targum Jerusalem, Genesis 3:9)
And the Word of the Lord God said, Behold, Adam whom I have created is
sole in my world, as I am sole in the heavens above. It is to be that
a great people are to arise from him; from him will arise a people who
will know how to discern between good and evil. And now it is good
that we keep him from the garden of Eden before he stretch forth his
hand and take also of the fruit of the tree of life, and eat, and live
for ever. (Targum Jerusalem, Genesis 3:22)
And the Word of the Lord had caused showers of favour to descend upon
Sedom and Amorah, to the intent that they might work repentance, but
they did it not: so that they said, Wickedness is not manifest before
the Lord. Behold, then, there are now sent down upon them sulphur and
fire from before the Word of the Lord from Heaven. (Targum Jonathan,
Genesis 19:24)
And the Word of the Lord said to Mosheh, He who spake to the world,
Be, and it was; and who will speak to it, Be, and it will be. And he
said, Thus shalt thou speak to the sons of Israel, EHEYEH hath sent me
unto you. (Targum Jerusalem, Exodus 3:14)
And the Lord was revealed in His Word unto Abraham, to Izhak, and to
Jakob, as the God of Heaven; but the Name of the Word of the Lord was
not known to them. (Targum Jerusalem, Exodus 6:3)
It is a night to be observed and celebrated for the liberation from
before the Lord in bringing forth the sons of Israel, made free from
the land of Mizraim. Four nights are there written in the Book of
Memorial. Night first; when the Word of the Lord was revealed upon the
world as it was created; when the world was without form and void, and
darkness was spread upon the face of the deep, and the Word of the
Lord illuminated and made it light; and he called it the first night.
Night second; when the Word of the Lord was revealed unto Abraham
between the divided parts; when Abraham was a son of a hundred years,
and Sarah was a daughter of ninety years, and that which the Scripture
saith was confirmed,--Abraham a hundred years, can he beget? and
Sarah, ninety year old, can she bear? Was not our father Izhak a son
of thirty and seven years, at the time he was offered upon the altar?
The heavens were (then) bowed down and brought low, and Izhak saw
their realities, and his eyes were blinded at the sight, and he called
it the second night. The third night; when the Word of the Lord was
revealed upon the Mizraee, at the dividing of the night; His right
hand slew the firstborn of the Mizraee, His right hand spared the
firstborn of Israel; to fulfil what the Scripture hath said, Israel is
My firstborn son. And he called it the third night. Night the fourth;
when the end of the age will be accomplished, that it might be
dissolved, the bands of wickedness destroyed and the iron yoke broken.
Mosheh came forth from the midst of the desert; but the King Meshiha
(comes) from the midst of Roma. The Cloud preceded that, and the Cloud
will go before this one; and the Word of the Lord will lead between
both, and they shall proceed together. This is the night of the Pascha
before the Lord, to be observed and celebrated by the sons of Israel
in all their generations. (Targum Jerusalem, Exodus 12:42)
And the Word of the Lord conducted the people by the way of the desert
of the sea of Suph; armed in good works went up the sons of Israel,
free from the land of Mizraim. (Targum Jerusalem, Exodus 13:18)


Interesting. One does wonder why John wrote "the Word was God" rather than "the Word was the firstborn of creation" if that is the meaning intended.

In English, we have three articles: a, an, and the. These are used to differentiate between definite and indefinite nouns.
For example:
a.  Did you eat a cookie? Did you eat an apple? These refer to an indefinite cookie or apple, and whether a or an is used depends on whether the noun begins with a consonant or a vowel.
b.  Did you eat the cookie? This refers to a definite (identifiable) cookie, perhaps the last one you were saving, or the one you’d rescued from your dog’s mouth (eww).
Greek articles don't at all work the same way:

You will soon discover that the Greeks do not use the article the same
way we do. They use it when we never would, and they omit it when
English demands it. Languages are not codes, and there is not an exact
word for word correspondence. Therefore, we must be a little flexible
at this point. — Dr. William D. Mounce, Basics of Biblical Greek

And the primary purpose of a Greek article

. . . is not to make something definite (though that’s what it does
most often—it identifies an object). Its primary purpose is to turn
something into a concept—and it can do that for just about any part of
speech as well as whole phrases. – Dr. Andy Naselli, How to Understand
and Apply the New Testament

The meaning of Greek articles depends on case, gender, and whether they’re plural or singular, and the purpose of including or not including an article has a different effect from English and is complex.
oh joy.
So, let’s see what happens when one incorrectly interprets ὁ Θεὸς as “a god” according to the original question. Where does this lead us when applied to different Greek texts that use the same two words?
The Greek Septuagint (LXX) was the authorized Greek translation of the Hebrew Tanakh (aka, the Old Testament) over 200 years before Christ under the auspices of the Jewish Sanhedrin. Let’s see how these translators, six scholars from each of the 12 tribes of Israel, understood Genesis 1:1,2 and Deuteronomy 6:4.
Genesis 1:1,2 is the very beginning of the Bible, unveiling God and creation. Deuteronomy 6:4 is something called the Shema, the opening centerpiece recitation for all Jewish prayer services, morning and evening:

שְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵינוּ יְהוָה אֶחָד׃
Šəmaʿ Yīsrāʾēl YHWH ʾĕlōhēnū YHWH ʾeḥād
Sh'ma Yisrael Adonai Eloheinu Adonai Eḥad
"Hear, O Israel! The Lord is our God! The Lord is One!" (or “. . . the
Lord alone!”)

So how were these verses translated into Greek by these 72 Jewish scholars? Here’s what we read from Charles Van der Pool's, Apostolic Bible Polyglot (a Greek-English interlinear translation of the LXX and the New Testament). In both of these passages, the Greek reads ὁ Θεὸς.

Thus, IF the correct translation of John 1:1 . . .  καὶ Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος is “and the Word was a god,” then “a god” created the universe in Genesis 1:1 and . . . our Lord is "a god” in Deuteronomy 6:4.
This can't be right!
But what might explain why a Coptic (or any other) translation chooses “a god” here?
Here's an excellent reference for the connection between the Coptic church and Gnosticism titled The School of Alexandria and the Gnostics:
https://www.copticchurch.net/patrology/schoolofalex/I-Intro/chapter4.html
Here are some quotes:

Gnosticism designates a complex religious and philosophical movement
that started probably before Christianity and flourished from about
100 to 700 A.D. There were many Christian, Jewish and pagan Gnostic
sects that stressed salvation through a secret "knowledge" or
"Gnosis."


At present, many scholars are inclined to believe that gnosticism is
built upon Hellenistic-Jewish foundations and can be traced to centers
like Alexandria, which had a large Jewish population.


Many of the Nag-Hammadi writings are Christ-centered. Their
understanding of Christ, the Scriptures and man differed fundamentally
from that of members of the Church. The function of Christ was to come
as the emissary of the supreme God, bringing "gnosis." As a Divine
Being, He neither assumed a properly human body nor died, but either
temporarily inhabited a human being (Jesus) or assumed a merely
phantasmal human appearance.


The great Egyptian Gnostics seem to all have been of Jewish birth. The
adherents of Basilides claimed, "We are no longer Jews and not yet
Christians." The followers of Valentinus reported, "When we were
Hebrews, we were orphans." Nevertheless, Basilides and Valentinus both
proclaimed a God beyond the Old Testament God.

The Coptic Gnostic Library contains all the Nag Hammadi codices here: https://scholarlyeditions.brill.com/cglo/
and here:
https://archive.org/details/gnosticism/Coptic%20Gnostic%20Library/BOOKS%20OF%20JEU_UNTITLED%20TEXT%20BRUCE%20CODEX%20%282%29/
During the late first century, Gnostic theologians organized, refined, and started unifying many existing theologies, including Jewish and early Christian beliefs, on a foundation of Aristotelian and Platonic mysticism. They rapidly spread these teachings across the world over the next several centuries.
References:
Joseph Dan, Jewish Gnosticism?
https://www.jstor.org/stable/40753137
G. Quispel, Gnosticism and the New Testament
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1582464
A rough representation of their most basic teachings includes the following:

The supreme but utterly remote Godhead is called the Monad.
From the Monad emanate lower pairs of divine beings called Aeons.
Among the 365 Aeons, the most well-known are "the Christ" and his consort, "Sophia (Wisdom)". The Holy Spirit is also an Aeon of salvation.
The offspring of the Aeons are called Demiurges, typically rebellious, often malevolent.
These Demiurges include Yaldabaoth, Samael (the blind God), Saklas (the foolish God), Ahriman, El, Satan, and Yahweh (the jealous, lesser deity who created the material universe and enslaved its people).
The Christ manifested himself on earth as “Jesus” to set humanity free from Yahweh by means of gnosis (or secret or inner knowledge).
Redemption, freedom, and elevation is achieved by people through asceticism and gnosis for which Jesus provided a way, himself as the personification of the Logos, the divine ordering principle of the cosmos.

Gnostic theology survives today in dozens of neo-gnostic movements, mystery cults, and doctrines. These include the Rosicrucian Society, Egyptian freemasonry, Theosophy (est. 1875), Archeosophical Society (est. 1968), and the Order of the Rose and Cross (est. 2022).
Some Gnostic teachings have also been adopted into various contemporary denominations and cults.

I had commented under another answer, "The problem of different translations can only be cleared up when the entire Prologue is considered" but in view of this answer, I must retract that! I reckon this answer should get the Green Tick, but I won't be surprised if it does not.

That little "o" your arrows point to is the Greek article. It could be "a" or "the" because Greek doesn't have a difference. Those graphics are factually misleading and need support.

@Jesse, you are correct regarding the Greek article. However, the original question asked specifically whether "the Word was a god" would be legitimized by the Coptic translation. That's why I added the question marks to my image. Then, I showed the effect of similarly translating the Greek article as an "a" to important passages in the LXX and suggested a motive why the Coptic translation chose to do so, namely Gnosticism. Does this help?

@Anne, Thank you. I'd always looked at the beginning of John as a prologue until I saw how David Stern formatted (indented) what he considered the quoted section versus John's commentary. I thought this was very profound and revealing. Then, I stumbled across Deborah Forger's PhD thesis regarding the connection to Philo, referencing it in a related answer here:https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/100044/does-john-16-12-and-13-refute-john-was-influenced-by-philos-writing-on-the-l/100109#100109.

Just say something about this, probably at the top of the post. Please help make sure that we correct the public's understanding about Greek articles and not pass on the misunderstanding. If it were me, I'd change those graphics to read "a/the God?", then say that the Coptic preferred "a" (without explanation, and it has both def and indef articles). My big question in all this is about why Coptic went indefinite instead of definite. It seems more that a polythism from the culture was an influence, but I'd want reasons for or against that.

Fair enough, @Jesse. I'll make some changes to my answer to make this clear. Good point also about the Coptic translation. Gnosticism seems to meld a polytheistic aspect to monotheism and was all the rage then. The evidence I presented is circumstantial, but you're right that it would help to find more of a "smoking gun" connection, if possible. Thanks!

@Jesse, Okay, I made some significant changes. The connection between the Gnostic "school of Alexandria" with Judaism and Christianity during Apostolic and even pre-Christian times is established, but the fallacious translation of "a god" is still circumstantial but fully compatible with Gnostic beliefs. So, I'm still looking for a "smoking gun" specifically connecting John 1 with the early Gnostics.

@Jesse, I was under the impression that as a determiner the g5388 functions as a definite article or a pronoun, but  would never be translated with an indefinite article if it is translated at all. Do you have an example where it's translated with an indefinite article in English?

@Dieter, how does your Gnostic theory account for the 6th-century Coptic version in a different Coptic dialect in the hotbed of Trinitarian belief after Gnostic influence dissipated by the 3rd century? If this translation really was anti-thetical to the Trinitarian/Monotheistic belief, how could it survive so long and in a different dialect? Blaming it on the Gnostics seems quite unlikely. It seems most parsimonious is that the dominant Trinitarians at that time didn't have a problem with it the way modern Trinitarians do.

@Austin, According to one of the quotes from the Coptic Church reference: "Gnosticism designates a complex religious and philosophical movement that started probably before Christianity and flourished from about 100 to 700 A.D." The Greek New Testament was translated into Coptic as late as the third century, contemporary with Gnostics and the school at Alexandria. Greek articles likely don't follow the same rules as Coptic, an Afro-Asiatic language. I already showed that "a god" doesn't work in the Greek LXX, so either the Coptic translators made a mistake or practiced biazogesis.

@Dieter, Checked out their website. While it's true that globally gnosticism flourished into 700 A. D. All of their examples of gnoticism in Egypt end in the 3rd century. Do you have evidence that gnosticism was prevalent in Egypt during the 5th and 6th century? "I already showed that "a god" doesn't work in the Greek LXX, so either the Coptic translators made a mistake or practiced biazogesis" The third option is they faithfully translated the Greek in Jn1:1c which is different than the Gk you cited, & the theology of the OT & NT is more complex than what your current hermeneutic allows.

That information is awesome! It provides a context. Some might think it is a bit long, some might think not long enough. It frames the context tho. This is a great read! Thanks so much for all this!

Thank you, @Jesse, the original question and subsequent comments forced to me research and learn things that I didn't know. :-)

The question is about whether or not the translation "and the word (or The Word) was a god" is objectively legitimate as a literal translation given the Coptic translations as opposed to "should" it be translated one way or the other.
While I have no knowledge of the Coptic translations or language, NT translations should be measured against the Greek rather than other translations. Linguistic differences alone preclude the possibility of a perfect literal translation. Add to that textural, cultural differences, etc., I cannot imagine any translation that is free of bias and error.
This response therefore regards only the use of the English indefinite article in translating Jn 1:1c. To address the OP’s question, I divided the functions of the indefinite article into three general categories with examples that reference the same individual (Note: this list is an interpretative tool only and not meant to be official or comprehensive):

indefinite/concrete: the noun is indefinite, indicating a concrete
but unidentified member of a class. Example: A woman came into the
room.
indefinite/qualitative: the noun is indefinite/qualitative,
indicating both the qualities of as well as membership within a
class. Example: She is a nurse.
qualitative/figurative: the noun is used figuratively and does
not reference a literal member of the class. Example: She is an angel.

The monotheism of John’s gospel precludes the possibility of there being more than one within the class of “God.” We already have “the God” in Jn 1:1b, so that rules out categories 1 and 2. But what about the third category? If the Word is not a literal member of the class “God,” technically it would not violate John’s monotheism.
Ultimately, I ruled out category 3 out as well, not on the basis of theology but context. John 1:1 precedes God’s work of creation. In that context, there can only be one in existence, and that is God. Like the other categories, 3 presupposes the existence of two: one who is God and another who is not God but who is God only in a qualitative/figurative sense.
As I understand it, the focus of Jn 1:1 is on the Word and the relationship between the Word and God. In the beginning, the Word was with (and therefore distinct from) the God. There is distinction, but distinction does not necessarily entail division and plurality. In the undifferentiated state before creation, I argue that it cannot.
The Greek articles identify and distinguish, while the anarthrous noun is fundamentally undifferentiated. If we translate John 1:1b and c with the articles as they are in the Greek, the semantic structure paints a compelling picture. On the one hand, the Word and the God are distinct from one another; on the other, there is one undifferentiated God.
   And the Word was with the God | And the Word was God

    καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν | καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος


When you say, "John’s gospel precludes the possibility of there being more than one within the class of “God.” - could I ask, "One what?" And does "the class of God" mean that which is deity, or the only true deity there is? Also, when verse 1 speaks of THE Word, that alone rules out being indefinite; with the Word taking definite, identifiable human form, later in time (vs.14). I'm just seeking a bit more clarity, not a debate!

@Anne I'm glad you asked. I really struggled with this question so perhaps you could help me articulate my points better. What I mean is that from a monotheistic perspective, there can be only one who is God and who properly falls under the category of "God." Those who are called god or gods fall under the category of "gods." With respect to the indefinite article, I was referring to whether it can precede the word God in Jn 1:1c. That "the Word" is definite is not under debate.

That is clear and well expressed. Thank you. Yes, John knew that there is only one true God. I would not add to that, nor would I answer the Q myself as it is not scoped to deal with the nuances of what John wrote in the verses following. The problem of different translations can only be cleared up when the entire Prologue is considered.

I must retract my last sentence above: "The problem of different translations can only be cleared up when the entire Prologue is considered" in view of the new answer from Dieter. He has answered beautifully, using the Greek language involved, and speaking knowledgeably on the Gnostic influence.

Ah! I think the 2 bright red instances of "A God?" with an arrow pointing to the Greek text which has "THE God" may have caused confusion. The point Dieter seems to be making is that the Greek text does, indeed, have the definite article. But some claim it really means "a god". It doesn't! Yet some have taken the liberty of putting the indefinite article into their translations. That's what I took to be the point of Dieter's illustration.

@Anne I see, but Θεὸς in Jn 1:1c has no article, so I'm not sure how Dieter's answer resolves the OP's question. In my examples above, the Greek would simply read "she is nurse" and "she is angel." How should/could we translate those statement into English? That is the gist of the OP's question.

'What I mean is that from a monotheistic perspective, there can be only one who is God and who properly falls under the category of "God." Those who are called god or gods fall under the category of "gods."' This makes no sense. An individual member of the class of gods would be called a god and would be rightly classified as a god and not a gods. It seems you're trying to disqualify the Coptic translation via a class distinction that doesn't make a lot of sense.

@Austin A "man" can fall under the category of "men." That's all I meant. The category "god" would work just as well. I just couldn't justify placing those who are called "god" (2 Co 4:4) or "gods" (Jn 10:35) in the same category of God as defined according to John's monotheistic perspective. Ultimately, I did not rule out the indefinite article based on John's theology but on context, one in which the Word existed prior to creation. As noted in my response, I did not address the Coptic translation.

You do eliminate at least option 2 based on your understanding of John's monotheistic understanding. However, that may be a little premature given John 10:34, and Job 38:4-7 from the OT and given that Jesus does not include himself as the only true God in Jn 17:1-3. If "a god" is a proper representation of the Greek, then we'd have cause to rethink how strictly we view the "all" and "nothing" statements that often enough really mean "all others" and often enough have obvious exceptions.

@Austin Given the controversy and the charges of bias regarding the translation of Jn 1:1c, I tried to be as objective and open-minded as I could in my examination of your question. I have satisfied myself at least that “a god” is not a viable rendering of the anarthrous θεὸς. Moreover, and quite unexpectedly, I am now more convinced than ever that the anarthrous θεὸς is a legitimate & undifferentiated way to reference the one true God, and that Jn 1:1c captures the mystery of the Word as one who does not fit any of our preconceived notions or humanly conceived categories.

Yes, the Coptic translation of John 1:1c proves that the word "theos" in Greek, without the article in this particular case, makes it an anarthrous qualitative noun which must be rendered "a god", exactly as done in 2 Corinthians 4:4.
John 1:1 in literal Greek to English reads,

In beginning was the word, and the word was with the god, and god was
the word.

John 1:1 in clean intelligible English reads,

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was himself a god.

John is telling us that at the beginning of creation, on Day 1 in Genesis 1:3, God created (spiritually brought forth) the Son as the first light of the world ("I am the light of the world"). The Son was then alongside God as a god also. The Father God is himself a god, yet the only eternal god, therefore he is "The God" with an article.
Jesus, the Word and Wisdom of God our Father, was created as "the first of his works of old" in Proverbs 8:22. Jesus is therefore the "firstborn of all creation" in Colossians 1:15, and the "beginning of the creation of God" in Revelation 3:14.
Jesus is the "only-begotten Son" of God our Father in that he is God's treasured firstborn Son, who is heir of all his Father's creation and through whom God created all things in Proverbs 8:30 and John 1:3.
The Son, Jesus, is the "first of the chief princes" and is therefore the Prince of the host, the Chief-Angel Michael. "Michael" means, "One who is like God", which is exactly whom Christ the Son of God is.
Because the Son is given the divine Name of God, the Tetragrammaton YHWH, he is the vizier or authorized agent of God who can speak on behalf of God as though he is God, even though he is not God.
That is why the Angel of YHWH, Michael, who is Christ, can be worshipped as God and channel messages to and from God, as he is the sole mediator between God and men.
I rest my word with two verses,
1 Corinthians 8:6,

For us there is one God, the Father, from whom are all things and for
whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things
and through whom we exist.

And 1 Corinthians 11:3.

The head of woman is man, the head of man is Christ, and the head of
Christ is God [the Father].

CONCLUSION:
There is only one God, the Father, who is the only eternal god and creator of all things.
There is only one Lord, the Son, who is the first created god and the agent of the creator.

The word "also" doesn't seem very literal. Why do you supply it in your version of John 1:1?

@Austin, the reason is because the Logos is being described with a qualitative noun; this means the Logos possesses the same quality as the Father: both of them are divine gods.

Got it. For theological, interpretive reasons and not in an attempt to be purely literal.

@Austin – John 1:1 literally reads, "In beginning was the Word, and the Word was with the God, and god was the Word." However, this is not grammatically readable, so we must carefully translate it without losing any original intent of the text. This is why "the" and "also" is supplied, so that the reader can understand what John actually meant in his Greek writing.

This is not correct. You need to take some classes in Greek. The articular theos in the first clause determines the proper noun status of the anarthrous theos in the third clause. That's not an opinion. That's Greek syntax.

@AFrazier – John 10:33-34 "...because you, being a man, makes yourself to be a god!" Jesus answered, "Do you not know that I have said in your Psalms, "You are gods, sons of the Most High?"

@AFrazier, that are several trinitarians that disagree with you, but prefer to interpret the theos in the third clause as qualitative and not as a proper noun (thought they may still prefer to capitalize the noun for the sake of monotheistic theological conventions)

@Austin – Greek doesn't capitalize anything. It is up to the English translators to carefully analyze the articles and nouns to make a proper translation that reflects the original writing, such as what I have done above.

@Austin, I don't care how many trinitarians disagree. Greek is how it is.

Again ... Well done!! + 1. Although see my comment given moments ago to your other John 1:1c answer. You have many downvotes here. Do not be discouraged by them.

@AFrazier, I'm talking about Trinitarian Greek scholars like Bill Mounce and Greek speakers on this site disagree with you.

@Austin, I gave a more thorough response to what is essentially the same question elsewhere. Give it a read. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/94155/65881

@AFrazier, thanks for sharing. I think I see where you went wrong. I'll comment on it on the post there instead of here.
