Does John 1:6, 12, and 13 refute John was influenced by Philo's writing on the Logos?
The "Logos" language in John's Gospel is found only in the Prologue and is understood by some as being influenced by the writings of Philo of Alexandria. Philo wrote to explain God as found in the LXX in terms of Greek philosophy. With respect to God in the LXX, Philo recognized a distinction when God was written with or without the article.

When the scripture uses the Greek term for God ho theos, it refers to the true God, but when it uses the term theos, without the article ho, it refers not to the God, but to his most ancient Logos (Somn. 1.229-230). 1

Many argue John 1:1 follows Philo's distinction on the use of the article.

In the beginning was the Logos, and the Logos was with ho theos (the true God), and the Logos was theos (a god).

If this is true, the Prologue's next three uses of theos are all without the article, and, according to Philo, should be understood as God's most ancient Logos.

There was a man sent from His Logos whose name was John. (1:6)
But to all who did receive him, who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of His Logos (1:12)
who were born, not of blood nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of His Logos (1:13).

It seems like a reader of the period who was familiar with Philo's ideas and understood verse 1 as a god, would continue to apply that line of reasoning until the Logos was made flesh. 2 Conversely, if a reader of the period rejected Philo's application in verse 6, 12, and 13, they would not apply it in verse 1.
Does John's omission of the article in verse 1:6, 12, and 13 refute the claim the Prologue was influenced by Philo's writings, or should we continue to understand John use of Philo's position theos without the article means His Logos until His Logos is made flesh after which the His Logos no longer follows anything Philo wrote?


Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy
Philo's concept of the Logos does not include being made flesh. If John was influenced by Philo, it is also clear he differed in this aspect. Thus verses 14-18 would be John's departure from Philo.


Ooo - I love this. Thank you for the Philo reference :) I'll have to dig into this more myself.

One small - possibly inconsequential- observation is that in those verses “God” is in the genitive case (theou). Thus the article that would go with it - if present - would be (tou) not the nominative singular masculine article (ho) mentioned in your quote. Ultimately Philo’s position appears to me to me to come from his familiarity with the Septuagint - so I’d suggest looking at genitive cases of God therein to see if John’s usage is consistent with it or not.

@RyanPierceWilliams That's a fair point, but it is the use, or lack, of the article that makes a difference. After the Prologue Θεοῦ is used 41 times, 35 with the article. So omitting the article is the uncommon treatment, as τὸν Θεόν (1:1, 2) shows.

I haven’t studied the Septuagint article usage enough to have an opinion one way or the other myself. I suspect you’d need to compare the Septuagint usage vs the Hebrew, in fact. It’s an interesting topic that definitely deserves an in depth analysis. I wouldn’t be surprised if there’s some scholarly articles somewhere that have done the leg work

This might serve to show that it was Arius and his views, right down to modern-day variations on his teachings, that show support of Philo, being influenced by him and not what the Apostle John taught.

Philo of Alexandria
First off, Philo Judaeus of Alexandria lived from about 10-15 BC to about 45-50 CE. His work includes syncretizing the Tanakh with Greek philosophy primarily by means of allegorical interpretation. For example, he identifies his Logos with Wisdom as personified in Proverbs 8, culminating in verse 22 and on:

The Lord possessed me at the beginning of his work, the first of his
acts of old.

John 1 as an Annotated Antiphonal Chant
Portions of John 1 indeed might have been a quote. Rabbi David H. Stern in his translation, Complete Jewish Bible, formatted the first part of John 1 in couplets as follows:

Verses 1-5 is indented as a quoted hymn or creed.

Verses 6-8 is the Apostle John's commentary.

Verses 9-11 is again indented as a quote.

Verses 12-13 is additional commentary.

Verse 14 is indented as a quote.

Verse 15 is commentary.

Verses 16-17 is a quote.

Verse 18 is commentary.


There’s a clear stylistic variation between the text and the commentary. Thus, the original text of this prologue, creed, hymn, or better yet, an antiphonal chant might have read as follows:

In the beginning was the Word,//
and the Word was with (toward) God,
and the Word was God.//
He was with (toward) God in the beginning.
All things came to be through him,//
and without him nothing made had being.
In him was life,//
and the life was the light of mankind.
The light shines in the darkness,//
and the darkness has not suppressed (overcome/comprehend) it.
This was the true light,//
which gives light to everyone entering the world.
He was in the world — the world came to be through him —//
yet the world did not know him.
He came to his own homeland,//
yet his own people did not receive him.
The Word became a human being and lived with us,//
and we saw his Sh’khinah,
the Sh’khinah of the Father’s only Son,//
full of grace and truth.
We have all received from his fullness,//
yes, grace upon grace.
For the Torah was given through Moshe;
grace and truth came through Yeshua the Messiah.

Much of the above exhibits binary opposites. Note that Deborah Forger's great comparison of Philo’s outlook and the Apostle John’s can be compared here: https://vridar.org/2019/01/28/philos-and-the-gospel-of-johns-logos-the-word/
However, when John writes that the Logos became a human in the form of Yeshua of Nazareth, Philo would likely have objected!
So the question where the annotated couplets in John 1 came from becomes fundamental. Also, it's possible that an original "Ode to the Logos" was extended beyond the phrase, “and the darkness has not suppressed it” into a Christian interpretation. No one knows without more evidence.
Let’s take an inventory in the New Testament where the “Word of God” might be either personified or objectified:

. . . and take the helmet of salvation, and the sword of the Spirit,
which is the word [SG4487 rhéma] of God – Ephesians 6:17 ESV


For the word [SG3056 Logos] of God is living and active, sharper than any two-edged
sword, piercing to the division of soul and of spirit, of joints and
of marrow, and discerning the thoughts and intentions of the heart. –
Hebrews 4:12 ESV


By faith we understand that the universe was created by the word [SG4487 rhéma] of
God, so that what is seen was not made out of things that are visible.
– Hebrews 11:3 ESV


. . . since you have been born again, not of perishable seed but of
imperishable, through the living and abiding word [SG3056 Logos] of God; – 1 Peter
1:23 ESV


For they deliberately overlook this fact, that the heavens existed
long ago, and the earth was formed out of water and through water by
the word [SG3056 Logos] of God, – 2 Peter 3:5 ESV


He is clothed in a robe dipped in blood, and the name by which he is
called is The Word [SG3056 Logos] of God. – Revelation 19:13 ESV

The last one in Revelation 19 is clearest, most literal association between Yeshua, the Lamb of God and the name by which he is called, namely "the Logos of God." But there's one more instance that's extremely important to our understanding of God.

He [the Son] is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint
of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word [SG4487 rhéma] of his power.
After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of
the Majesty on high - Hebrews 1:3 ESV

Words have consequences. So, what's the significance of the distinction between SG3056, Logos and SG4487 rhéma? These words have some similarity but are definitely not synonyms.
Checking the authoritative BDAG definitions

rhéma is 1. "that which is said" or 2. "an event that can be spoken about"

Logos is 1. "a communication whereby the mind finds expression" or 2. "computation, reckoning" or 3. "the independent, personified expression of God, the Logos"


Regarding 3, the BDAG goes on to explain,

"Our literature shows traces of a way of thinking that was widespread
in contemporary syncretism, as well as in Jewish wisdom literature and
Philo . . .

Which way did the personification and veneration of the Logos travel?
Most of Proverbs, including Proverbs 8, was likely written during the time of Solomon, who reigned from 971-931 BCE. Proverbs was edited during the time of Hezekiah around 200 years later. However, the earliest Greek philosophers are dated to the 6th century BCE, which is later. Thus, ancient Hebrew writings personified Wisdom as the means for creation in context of Genesis 1, in which YHWH speaks words that result in things coming into physical existence.
Did it come from Philo after all?
Maybe. Philo came into the picture as a famous Jewish philosopher who was syncretizing the Tanakh with the Logos, as Deborah Forger notes in her doctoral thesis, Divine Embodiment in Jewish Antiquity: Rediscovering the Jewishness of John’s Incarnate Christ.

Forger, Deborah. 2017. “Divine Embodiment in Jewish Antiquity: Rediscovering the Jewishness of John’s Incarnate Christ.” PhD Thesis,
Ann Arbor, MI: University of Michigan, Horace H. Rackham School of
Graduate Studies.
https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/138783.

What about Greek articles
As to the usage of the articles, I'm not familiar enough with Greek to explain the grammatical rules, however, Greek articles don't at all work the same way as English articles:

You will soon discover that the Greeks do not use the article the same
way we do. They use it when we never would, and they omit it when
English demands it. Languages are not codes, and there is not an exact
word for word correspondence. Therefore, we must be a little flexible
at this point. — Dr. William D. Mounce, Basics of Biblical Greek

And the primary purpose of a Greek article

. . . is not to make something definite (though that’s what it does
most often—it identifies an object). Its primary purpose is to turn
something into a concept—and it can do that for just about any part of
speech as well as whole phrases. – Dr. Andy Naselli, How to Understand
and Apply the New Testament

Thus, if John was quoting and commenting on a portion of Philo's work, it would make sense to conclude that John (or whoever John was quoting) "reverse-syncretized" Philo into Christianity, and, of course, using Greek grammatical conventions.

Philo simply noticed what the Old Testament teaches, and John expounded on it in the Spirit.

@OneGodOneLord I think you miss the point on Philo's position over the usage of the article in the LXX. Theos with the article was "God" and without was "Logos." So after verse 1:11a & b which some claim appeals to Philo's concept of the Logos, the article or lack of article would be a matter of following Philo's statement. 1:1c is Logos; 1:2 is God, 1:6 is Logos; 1:12-13 are Logos. IOW, while it might appear John is employing Philo's philosophical concept, in fact he is using Philo's belief about theos without the article to say theos is Logos in 1:6 and 1:12-13.

I just posted my answer above with major revisions. As to the presence or absence of an article before Theos, this is also the case in numerous other Greek manuscripts, including the LXX, and is likely a Greek grammatical convention. If anyone can authoritatively confirm or falsify my conclusion, I'd appreciate it very much and will update my answer above. Thanks!

I recently started reading through "Truth in Translation" by Jason David BeDuhn, and it has a chapter devoted to the translation of John 1:1. It is extremely well written and presents an objective case for why θεος in John 1:1 should be understood to be indefinite ("a god / divine") rather than definite ("God") based upon Greek Grammar rules generally and NT usage of (ο) θεος specifically.
pg 125 states:

The noun theos ("god") in the nominative ("subject") form is used two-hundred-ninety-eight times in the New Testament. In two-hundred-seventy-four of those occurrences, the definite article is used. The definite articile specifies that the reference is to "the god," that is, "God," with three exceptions...
The large number  also suggests that, despite all the variety of style and expression found among the books of the New Testament, there is a standard way to refer to God, namely, ho theos.

Note that the three exceptions are still instances where "god" is definite, but from the context it is clear that "the god(s)" in question is not God proper: 2 Corinthians 4:4; Philippians 3:19; Acts 14:11.
This leaves only 24 instances in the New Testament where θεος appears without the article. It is clear both from the grammar and from contextual usage that these are used indefinitely ("a god").
pg 126:

Luke 20:38 reads: "But he is not a god of the dead" (theos de ouk estin nekron). Notice that in this verse theos is before the verb (estin), just as it is in John 1:1. The article is missing not because of "Colwell's Rule," but because theos is indefinite. The implied question is: What kind of god is the Christian god? The answer is: He is not a god of the dead, but a god of the living. The word "god" is indefinite because it is speaking of a category to which the subject belongs.

pg 127:

In Revelation 21:7, God promises, "I will be a god to him, and he will be a son to me" (esomai autoi theos kai autos estai moi huios). Since "god" (and "son") is a predicate nominative and follows the verb, it must be indefinite. God is characterizing the kind of relationship he will have with the one of whom he is speaking. How will that person relate to God? He will act towards him as to "a god" (in other words, will act toward him with worship and service). God, likewise, will act towards that one as towards "a son." Characterization is achieved through categorization, and "god" and "son" function here as such categories. Therefore, they are indefinite.

Again, pg 127:

In Philippians 2:13, Paul states, "For it is a god who is working in you" (theos gar estin ho energon en humin). The implied question is: What sort of thing is working in/among us? Paul's answer is that it is not a human force, or a demonic one, but a divine one. He is stating the character of the experience, the category to which the agency acting in these people's lives belongs. Therefore the indefinite is used.

Throughout the chapter, the author also makes good and explicit use of John Harner's article, "Qualitative Anarthrous Predicate Nouns: Mark 15:39 and John 1:1."
pg 120:

Based on [Harner's] investigation, he concludes that, "anarthrous predicate nouns preceding the verb may function primarily to express the nature or character of the subject, and this qualitative significance may be more important than the question whether the predicate noun itself should be regarded as definite or indefinite" (Harner 1973, page 75). In other words, Greek has a particular way of expressing the nature or character of something that employs predicate nouns before the verb and without the arcile, as as in John 1:1. The nature of character of ho logos ("the Word") is theos ("divine").

He also notes that the nominative case is, in fact, unique in it's dependence on the article to denote a noun as definite. On pg 117 he writes:

Others have argued that theos does not require the definite article to be definite, and that there are examples of article-less ("anarthrous") theos used definitely in the New Testament. While this may be true of anarthrous theos in the genitive or dative cases, two forms that freely dispense with the article in a number of uses, it is not the case for anarthrous theos in the nominative case, the form used in John 1:1c. The nominative case is much more dependent than other Greek cases on the definite article to mark definiteness.
There is a very limited range of definitizing elements that may make
an anarthrous nominative theos definitive. These include the presence
of an attached possessive pronoun (John 8:54; 2 Corinthians 6:16), the
use of the noun in direct address (the "vocative" function, Romans
9:5; 1 Thessalonians 2:5), and the association of the noun with the
numeration "one" (1 Corinthians 8:6; Ephesians 4:6; 1 Timothy 2:5). None of these definitizing elements are present in John 1:1c

To conclude, then, it would appear that the practice described by Philo in your quote - of how the presence of the article (ο) with the word god (θεος) is used to refer to the true God as opposed to "a god" - was standard practice in ancient / koine Greek generally, and a practice that is consistently applied across the New Testament specifically. And within John 1:1 we see that it is the indefinite, anarthrous θεος that is applied to ο λογος. For John, as with Philo, the Word is divine but not God proper.

Then 1:6 and 1:12-13 are also a god?

@RevelationLad those verses use the genitive case; different grammar rules apply. As noted in the quotes above, both the genitive and dative cases are much more loose with the article.

ἴδε ὁ ἀμνὸς τοῦ θεοῦ ὁ αἴρων τὴν ἁμαρτίαν τοῦ κόσμου John 1:29  κἀγὼ ἑώρακα καὶ μεμαρτύρηκα ὅτι οὗτός ἐστιν ὁ υἱὸς τοῦ θεοῦ John 1:34 ἴδε ὁ ἀμνὸς τοῦ θεοῦ John 1:36 ἰδεῖν τὴν βασιλείαν τοῦ θεοῦ John 3:3 :εἰσελθεῖν εἰς τὴν βατὰ ῥήματα τοῦ θεοῦ λαλεῖσιλείαν τοῦ θεοῦ John 3:5 τοῦ μονογενοῦς υἱοῦ τοῦ θεοῦ John 3:18 τὰ ῥήματα τοῦ θεοῦ λαλεῖ John 3:34 ἀλλ᾽ ἡ ὀργὴ τοῦ θεοῦ μένει ἐπ᾽ αὐτόν John 3:36, etc, etc. So the rule of the genitive not taking the article, is simply not true.

@RevelationLad the rule is that the genitive and dative may drop the article more easily for a definite noun phrase than in the nominative; not that the article must be dropped. Finding examples of the article present in the genitive doesn’t establish anything. And, at any rate, I didn’t write the book - I’d suggest getting it and reading it yourself, review the source material / grammars, etc. He would reference Smyth’s grammar therein; which I think you can find online.

I suggest being more familiar with Philo's use of the genitive. For example,  Commenting on Genesis 9:6 Philo states the reference to creation of man after the image of God is to the second deity, the Divine Logos of the Supreme being and to the father himself, because it is only fitting that the rational soul of man cannot be in relation to the preeminent and transcendent Divinity (QG 2.62). ὁ ἐκχέων αἷμα ἀνθρώπου ἀντὶ τοῦ αἵματος αὐτοῦ ἐκχυθήσεται ὅτι ἐν εἰκόνι θεοῦ ἐποίησα τὸν ἄνθρωπο Philo does not use the article when referring to the Logos as "God" in the genitive.

Again, the grammar governing the use of the definite article in the  genitive and dative cases are distinct from those for the nominative. And, at any rate, Philo didn’t invent koine Greek; he was writing in a manner that his Gentile, Greek audience would understand.

Isn't a key aspect of Philo's Logos acting as an intermediary? If John was influenced by Philo, why would you think "God" sent John and not the Logos?

It is doubtful that John relied on Philo, unless you are going to suggest that there was a period of time after the death of Christ that John did not have a full blown Logos Christology.
Most of Philo's authored works are thought to have been written sometime between 10-50AD, with some even suggesting a date as late as 60AD.
The problem is: Even if we supposed an early date for Philo (i.e., 10AD), does that then mean that the apostle John did not have a fully developed Logos Christology in 9AD?  What exactly did John believe about the pre-existent Christ in 9AD?
If we suppose Philo wrote in 20AD, does that mean 20 years would pass before John would begin formulating his Logos Christology? Assuming Philo didn't begin writing til 20AD, what did John's Christology look like prior to 20AD?
The only way around hurdles like these, is to say that John was not an eye-witness and was born (or at least, educated) sometime after Christ's death.  But if we take the author at his word, that he himself is an eye-witness of Christ, then the author would have had to have been in his mid-20's when encountering Christ.  Thus, the author of John's gospel and Philo were probably not too far apart in age, if   truly an eye-witness.
That said, to suggest that John was influenced by Philo is about as wild as the suggestion that Philo could have been influenced by what was happening on the world's center stage during that period; by that little blurb in world history: Christianity.  After all, the religion had such a little impact on the world, that even the Jews of Jesus' day paid no mind! Of course, I'm being facetious when I say that.  But with this in mind, this would not of course mean that Philo was educated by Christians, but that he could have caught a wiff of what was being circulated, and as a result tried to fit it back into his very own Jewish framework.
In order to show that John was reliant on Philo, one needs to demonstrate the broad outreach of Philo's works.  How quick did they move and how far did they go?  In how many laps did Philo's works have to land before they were recopied by scribes and redistributed for circulation?  And how many times would the works have to be recopied before it would eventually land in the lap of John?
From this vantage point, the notion that Philo was influenced by the events unfolding in his day (Christianity) explains this phenomonon better than Philo's influence on Christians.  Not to mention, the Gospel of John was probably not penned with the intention to evangelize Alexandria, or really even written to an Alexandrian audience.  John never went to Alexandria, so there was never chance to be influenced by it's trends, least it be through it's literature.
The Gospel of Mark (which lacks John's Logos Christology) may have been the gospel that was intended to help evangelize Alexandria.  At the end of the day, John's gospel did reach Alexandria, but to say that was the original intention of the work, or that it was influenced by Alexandrian thought (or, moseso Philo) is an overstatement.
One needs to demonstrate that Philo's works were in broad circulation prior to the Gospel of John.  I know of no such evidence that suggests that Philo was broadly cited, quoted, or replicated in other contemporary sources until sometime around the dawn of the 2nd c.  The difference between Philo's work and John's gospel narrative is that John's work was being advanced through the lens of the crucifixion of Christ.  In sorts, John's gospel was riding on the curtails of an event that impacted the world's center stage so dramatically beyond anything Philo could have done on his own. That said, John would only naturally reach wider audiences.  Philo's works would probably not have the same impact.
Are there references to Philo's works in other contemporary sources of the period?  Perhaps other philosophers of the period interacted with Philo.
It is more probable that John was already developing his Logos Christology, and that he and Philo had a common ancestor: The constant of their day.  Most authors of the period (including Philo) were being influenced by Plato's Timaeus.
If we look at some of the earlier NT materials, such as Paul's works (1 Corinthians, Phillipians), there are indications that he relied on sources that predate Philo.  There is an excellent paper written by Eliezer González entitled, Paul's Use of Metomorphisis in its Graeco-Roman and Jewish Contexts.  In it, he shows a close correlation between Paul's letter to the Philipians, and Euripides’ Bacchae playwrite.  He doesn't go into every detail, but there are likely two other times in Philippians (specifically in Phil. 1 and Phil. 3) that Paul may allude to other Euripidean playwrites.
People are reading far too much into Philo.  For one, Philo is offering a commentary on Gen. 31:13 LXX, and is not making a broad sweeping statement about grammar, or about the Logos.  He is simply giving us his interpretation of a specific text, namely, Gen. 31:13 LXX.  Philo makes this clear by emphasizing that it is “on this present occasion” that what he goes on to describe, is true.  He then emphasizes it again when he says, “what he here calls God is his most ancient word.”
Philo refers to the Word as “the house of God.”  The idea here is that God dwells in this “abode,” i.e., the Word.  In a sense, the Word is God's “tabernacle,” if you would.  Not that the Word is “a god,” but rather, that this Word is the one that houses God's being.  This idea that Philo is intending us to understand the anarthrous θεὸς in an indefinite sense is nowhere stressed or indicated by Philo.  People are simply pouncing at the opportunity and reading into Philo's statement what is not present, without recognizing that what he's trying to communicate is that there is a distinction between God and the Word, but this Word is God's personal dwelling space.  The Word is the “lens” through whom God is seen.
This is quite significant, because we can in turn use this to our benefit:
That the qualitative force in Jn. 1:1c lays stress on the fact that this figure dubbed “the Word” is none other than the one in whom God resides, and through this Word whom He (God) mediates Himself to men.  God is communicating, or revealing Himself through this Word.  This then becomes more of a sense of agency and mediation, a conclusion you can only get to except for the qualitative θεὸς.
However, with that said, it should also be noted that John does not allude to Gen. 31:13 LXX anywhere in his prologue or even in his gospel account.  It would be far closer of a connection had Philo made these comments on Gen. 1:1, and not Gen. 31:13.  After all, John's prologue places the Word in the creation narrative.  Not in a narrative On Dreams, of all places.

I'm not saying John needed to accept or even understand all of Philo's works. I'm simply taking up the scholarly argument used to argue John was influenced by Philo. If that is the case, then shouldn't we be consistent and say, like Philo would, theos in verse 1:6, 1:13, and 1:13 are the Logos? So if someone asked what type of "a" theos was the Logos, John's answer is found in 1:3 to 1:13. In particular the Logos was a theos who sent John and gave people the authority to become children of the Logos. If those are impossible, then how can we say "a" theos in John 1:1c is from Philo?

I'm unsure who you are interacting with, but I would simply point out: That passages like Jn. 1:6 and 1:13 demonstrate that John is not following the verbal patterns of Philo, in the way they suggest of Philo.  Nothing more, nothing less.

@RevelationLad I have also added a few additional details that I think may help.  I personally think people are reading too far into what Philo is saying.
